# Convert a List of object to a Tuple array

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, tuples

Have a tuple array and List of object defined as:

```
Tuple<string, string, string>[] phone_type 
List<Tele> telecomm

 public class Tele
{   public string number;
    public string displayNumber;
    public string type;
}
```

I want to to assign the values present in the `List<Tele>` to the tuple array. The below code doesn't work.

```
obj.phone_type[0] = (Tuple<string,string,string>) obj1.telecommunication[0];
```

Error says cast is redundant, cannot convert `List` to `Tuple<string,string,string>`

Is there a clean way to assign a specific/All element/s of the List to a tuple array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having:

```
public class Tele
{   
    public string number;
    public string displayNumber;
    public string type;
}
```

You can try:

```
List<Tele> telecomm = //a list of Teles

Tuple<string, string, string>[] phone_type  = 
    telecomm.Select(i => new Tuple<string, string, string>(i.number, i.displayNumber, i.type))
            .ToArray();
```

**EDIT:** also you may want to take a look at the @Kyle comment for improvement.

Comment: You can avoid having to specify the type arguments to the `Tuple` constructor by using `Tuple.Create( i.number, i.displayNumber, i.type )` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since C# has native support for `ValueTuple` now, you can also use:

```
var phone_type = telecom.Select(t => (t.number, t.displayNumber, t.type)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a method to Tele. You'd have to write it, but only once.

```
public Tuple<string, string, string> ToTuple() {
    return new Tuple<string, string, string>(number, displayNumber, type);
}
```

Then to populate the array, it's just like the answer from Hossein:

```
telecom.Select(t => t.ToTuple()).ToArray();
```